# Chartjs: old data being displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm currently having a problem which seems to be well known already, but of the answer provided none have worked so far for me.

Whenever I'm hovering over the line in a linegraph, the chart changes back to a chart displayed before as shown in the GIF below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmknf.gif

The solution which seemed the best to me so far is destroying the chart before creating a new one if it's not the first set of data. (bool 'first' and chart 'pauzeAmountChart' are global variables)

```
function setupAvgPauseGraph(currVideo, currData) {
        if (!first) {
            pauzeAmountChart.destroy();
        }

        first = false;

        var ctx = document.getElementById("pauzeduurChart");

        ...

        avgPauseChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Gemiddelde pauzeduur / seconde',
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {ticks: {min: 0, stepSize: step}}],
                    xAxes: [
                        {scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Seconden in video'}}]
                },
                elements: {point: {radius: 0}}
            }
        });

    }
```

However, when it's not the first dataset, thus getting to the line 'pauzeAmountChart.destroy()' AND which means the chart already has been initialized and filled with data before, I get this error:

http://prntscr.com/e57x4a

I'm unfortunately not sure what this error means, and Google didn't help me any further either.

Also, when I keep switching between the data the error appears again + 1 more time compared to the previous time the error appeared. Which means it's not actually destroying the graph? (So try #x to show the data gives x errors)

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you in advance!

[EDIT]

Thanks to Guus Punt it's fixed! With a few adjustments, it works now. See below for solution:

```
function setupPauzeAmountGraph(currVideo, currData) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("aantalPauzesChart");

        ...

        if (pauzeAmountChart != undefined) {
            pauzeAmountChart.chart.config.data.labels = labels;
            pauzeAmountChart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data = data;

            pauzeAmountChart.update();
        } else {
            pauzeAmountChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Aantal pauzes / seconde',
                        data: data,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [
                            {ticks: {min: 0, stepSize: step}}],
                        xAxes: [
                            {scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Seconden in video'}}]
                    },
                    elements: {point: {radius: 0}}
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to run your example to be sure but maybe the following would help.

Instead of destroying the chart you can add and remove datasets,

- Remove dataset before adding new data

  ```
  data.labels = []; //Empty label array
  data.datasets.splice(0, 1);//Removes first dataset
  ```
- Add new dataset and labels
- Update chart

  ```
  pauzeAmountChart.update();
  ```

I have a working example which retrieves new data from a webapi and updates every 10 seconds, if this isnt sufficient

Comment: Thank you very much Guus! Works like a charm with a few edits!

Comment: Glad to help. Struggled a few hours myself when i just started, ended with creating my own chartjs object.